# Rewrite rule for seo - title in url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Lets say I want users to be able to type this url in:

```
www.website.com/blog/2453/I-gained-0.1%-more-scripting-knowledge-!
```

I'm trying to include title information in the url for seo benefits.

I also want to include an id for my query. Effectively I want to pick up the id and **ignore** the title stuff that comes after, bearing in mind its user generated text so could contain any special characters in it.

How can I write a .htaccess rewrite rule so that the server reads it as the following with the appropriate GET data:

```
www.website.com/blog.php?id=2453
```

This is what I have tried but frankly I am way out of my depth here:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  blog.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

The rewrite rule you are using should work except for the `.`, `%`, and `!` characters that are in your URL.  The `%` characters is not safe to use in URLs because it has a special meaning in the URL syntax.  I wouldn't use exclamation points either.

If the ID is always going to be numeric, use `([0-9]+)` instead of `([A-Za-z0-9-]+)`.

Try this URL:

```
www.website.com/blog/2453/I-gained-0.1-more-scripting-knowledge
```

With this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)/[A-Za-z0-9\-\.]+/?$  blog.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```